# Show that there is a real positive solution

Tags: sequences-and-series, harmonic-numbers

Show that there exists a real positive $n$ such that

$(n+1) \left (1+\dfrac{1}{2}+\dfrac{1}{3}+\dfrac{1}{4}\cdots\dfrac{1}{n+1} \right ) \geq 5280n$

Comment: Is there a reason you think this is true? What have you tried?

Comment: Well, I have tried to decrease 5280 to smaller values, such as 2, 3, and 4, and I have found values for $n$ in those smaller cases. however, I am not able to actually show/prove that there is a solution.

Comment: @chezbgone Do you know $\lim_{n \to\infty}(1 + 1/2 + \ldots + 1/n)$?

Comment: Yes, it is infinite, but the expression on the right will increase at a faster rate than the harmonic series.

Comment: $\frac{n}{n+1}$ is bounded

Answer (score 3):

Suppose for the sake of contradiction that there is no real positive $n$ such that

$$(n+1) \left (1+\dfrac{1}{2}+\dfrac{1}{3}+\dfrac{1}{4}\cdots\dfrac{1}{n+1} \right ) \geq 5280n.$$

Then we would have, for all $n$,

$$\left (1+\dfrac{1}{2}+\dfrac{1}{3}+\dfrac{1}{4}\cdots\dfrac{1}{n+1} \right ) < 5280\frac{n}{n+1}<5280,$$

implying that the infinite harmonic series converges to a sum less that $5280$. If you know that the harmonic series diverges, you have your contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1k\simeq\ln n$.